# Camcorders that can stream directly to YouTube

Tags: live, camcorder

I've googled for the last couple hours and couldn't find any real answers. In short, are there any camcorders that allow you to live stream your video straight to **YouTube**. All the camcorders with live streaming capabilities that I've found only seem to mention UStream, but this isn't good enough unfortunately.

**Edit**

I'd preferably like to do this on the go as A lot of camcorders nowawadays have Wi-Fi capabilities.

This must be possible as like I mentioned, you can do so to UStream. Also, GoPros can do it, but these aren't good enough for me because they lack a flip screen and are too small to hold

Answer (score 2):

The "JVC GY-HM200SPU 4KCAM Compact Handheld Streaming Camcorder" claims... "When equipped with an optional Wi-Fi or 4G LTE high-speed broadband modem, the camcorder can deliver a live video stream directly to USTREAM and YouTube, while simultaneously recording HD video internally to SDHC/SDXC memory cards. "

I believe there are other camcorders in the JVC range, and almost certainly in cameras from other brands that will live-stream to YouTUbe.

https://www.bhphotovideo.com/c/product/1206407-REG/jvc_gy_hm200sp_4kcam_compact_handheld.html

Answer (score 1):

You don't necessarily need a *camcorder* with the built-in ability to stream to YouTube, but rather, a camcorder (or any camera, really) that you can use as an **input device** to a computer. If you can use a camera as an input device (think of it like a super-high quality webcam of sorts), then you can live stream to YouTube, UStream, Twitch, etc., using a free software like [OBS](https://obsproject.com/) from your computer.

I could see it being unrealistic to include streaming capabilities inside a camera itself because this would require the camera to be able to connect to the internet, use a live stream key, connect to YouTube, etc. It's much simpler to just use a camera as an input device to a computer and let the computer handle the tough networking issues.

Comment: Should have been clearer in my Q, it has been edited

Comment: What purpose is this for? Have you considered maybe just using a smartphone?